# "Your IP: ex. 000.00.000.00 : Your domain gmail.com is not allowed in header From"

Tags: phpmailer

When someone tries to contact me through contact form i receive this "Your IP: ex. 000.00.000.00 : Your domain gmail.com is not allowed in header From" what is it??

I tried to contact the support, but they can't help.

Comment: You can use SMTP to send email through google's servers: Here are two tutorials: https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en and https://netcorecloud.com/tutorials/send-an-email-via-gmail-smtp-server-using-php/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This will be because you're trying to send your contact form data as an email sent from your gmail.com address, but without sending it through gmail's servers. Gmail doesn't let you do this – their DMARC and SPF config prevents you from doing it.

So you need to either send through Gmail's servers, or use an address that's not handled by gmail.